# How to atomically create the file if it does not exist in Qt5?

Tags: c++, qt

I need to create a file with checking if it was not created before. I need to do this atomically, like:

```
int fd = open("/tmp/testfile", O_CREAT | O_EXCL);
```

Is there a way to do this in Qt 5?

Comment: Do you need a portable solution? If not, then why not use the POSIX `open` function like you do now, and then use the overloaded [`QFile::open`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html#open-2) to set the file descriptor in a `QFile` object?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes, I wanted a portable solution in Qt-way via QFile, but I was unable to find such open flags for it, so I have asked here.. Your solution seems fine to me. P.S. I think there can not be a portable solution since even `fopen` does not have such an ability but only in `glibc`.

Comment: if you try to create a file that already exists, isn't that either a no-op or an error?

Comment: @xaxxon Yes, so I don't want to create the file if it already exists but only if it does not.

Comment: If you open the file with QFile and an open mode of ReadWrite, won't that do what you want?

Comment: @xaxxon I have to dig deeper into the `QFile` source code to know what it does exactly in this mode. So I am asking here how to do this with Qt5. I did not find any information about how to do this atomically. So I am not sure `QFile::open` with `ReadWrite` does this atomically instead of `stat` and `opening` later, for example.

Comment: It would be pretty broken if it did anything else.  Filesystems are intrinsically safe to be used from multiple processes at the same time.

Comment: @xaxxon who knows? :) That is why I have asked my question here about doing this in Qt5 :)

Comment: @VictorPolevoy I don't really get what your game is here but if you want some sort of proof you'll have to dig through the OS and filesystem code.   Otherwise you should just accept that QFile is going to be calling open() under the hood, which will hook into the filesystem code and do the best that is possible on the current platform for "If the file does not exist it will be created. "  https://linux.die.net/man/2/open

Comment: @xaxxon, I think you're misunderstanding the question - it's looking for a Qt-portable equivalent of `O_EXCL`, which is supposed to _fail_ if the file _exists_ (rather than ensuring the file is created when it doesn't exist).  Exclusive opening semantics don't seem to be provided in Qt, and I'm guessing that's because some platforms don't provide that kind of locking.

Answer (score 0):

Qt 5.11 introduced the `QIODevice::NewOnly` flag.

> Fail if the file to be opened already exists. Create and open the file
> only if it does not exist. There is a guarantee from the operating
> system that you are the only one creating and opening the file. Note
> that this mode implies WriteOnly, and combining it with ReadWrite is
> allowed. This flag currently only affects QFile. Other classes might
> use this flag in the future, but until then using this flag with any
> classes other than QFile may result in undefined behavior.